# "suggested edits pending approval" indication

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

I have this indication now, showing the number 2.

Header Image:

[image]

Header Image w/ Tooltip:

[image]

When clicking on it, I get a page saying:

> Page Not Found
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.
>
> - Try searching for it
> - Browse recent questions
> - Browse popular tags
>
> ... etc...

What exactly is this "edits pending" feature, and why do I get this error message?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing. I see it as well. Interestingly if I edit the URL to http://photo.stackexchange.com/review/ I get to a working page that allows me to review 'new users' questions/answers. New 'partially implemented' functionality? Bug? Something else entirely? Inquiring minds want to know! :-)

Comment: Added the images for clarification...

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have it, too. It seems to be a relatively-new SE feature (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work). Maybe photo.se just found a bug in it?

Comment: Incidentally, today I received the "edit" privilege (2000 reps). I assumed this indicator is related to the new status. But now I see that I am not alone in this boat. Probably a new feature.

Comment: Ah! seems to be working OK now.